# Lexer Error: Unexpected next character (tilda ~ in property name)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to parse or get value of field, which have special character in field name? I am getting following error:

> Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 28-28 [~] in
>   expression [report.VALUE_MAP.LOGIN_DATA~LOGIN_DATE]

I want to get value of

```
<td>{{report.VALUE_MAP.LOGIN_DATA~LOGIN_DATE}}</td>
```

Comment: Use bracket/string notation like in normal JS?

Comment: can you elaborate more about that..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found similar issue described here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7469

Try this workaround:

```
 <td>{{report.VALUE_MAP['LOGIN_DATA~LOGIN_DATE']}}</td>
```

I assume that `LOGIN_DATA~LOGIN_DATE` is the problematic name of property

**What happens under the hood is this**

AngularJS's $parse service will try to evaluate the expression `report.VALUE_MAP.LOGIN_DATA~LOGIN_DATE`. It will try to traverse scopes and nested objects to get to the last property and retrieve it's value. But the `tilde ~` has a special meaning in javascript. (Read about it here http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/great-mystery-of-the-tilde/) So the tilde `~` confuses the parser. It's better to avoid it in property names.

When you have no control over the property names and you absolutely have to go with the tilda in property name, then you have to use this syntax instead `object['propertyname']`.

See this plunker with example http://plnkr.co/edit/8WKRLktv2tuePqAFvkDY

Comment: i have to use that variable name. so is there any way to parse that..?

Comment: @sumitchoudhary I have updated my answer and added link to example plunker